# Ember Data 1.0.0: this.modelFor('author').save fails - how to save a newly created record in the controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am migrating from EMber data 0.13 to 1.0.0 beta.  According to the documentation (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md), the following should work:

```
App.AuthorsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function () {
    return this.store.createRecord('author');
  },

  actions: {
    save: function() {
      this.modelFor('author').save();
    }
  }
})
```

However, in my case, I always get a "Cannot call method 'save' of undefined" error".

When using "this.get('**currentModel**').save();", it works when using the save action in the route.  When putting the save action in the controller, *it no longer works*.  Same error: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined" error.

How can I access the newly created record in the controller and save it ?

Can somebody provide a simple example ?

thx
Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You right to use this in the route :

`this.get('currentModel').save();`

In the controller you should use :

`this.get('model').save();`

Comment: nice, the PR author itself :)

Comment: Thx. Indeed, this works.  Thus documentation is partly wrong (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md).  Now up to error handling; replacement of becameError, becameInvalid.

Comment: Hi Tchak, What is this.get('currentModel') .Please explain.Please provide me any working example